# Preventing mouseUp event on a DIVs scrollbars

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to hide popup menus on my page:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".dropDownMenuOptions");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Works great, however in a few cases the popup can be quite large, so I've set the DIV to have a max-height of x-amount of pixels, which then shows a scroll-bar as one would expect.

The problem is however that if the user uses their mouse-wheel button, they can navigate the list of options BUT if they use the scroll-bars, this registers the mouseup event and thus causes the popup to disappear.

Is there anyway I can tell the mouseup function to ignore a scrollbar click or any other possible way to achieve what I'm after?

I'm trying to wrap my head around what is causing the problem.  I get the code will run if the mouseup is out of the container, but surely the scrollbar is part of the container and thus shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Same behaviour on all major browsers? Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, are u using any customized menu popup like you mentioned $(".dropDownMenuOptions").. if yes can you share that snippet, It will help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't it fix your issue?!

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHhRf/)

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".dropDownMenuOptions");
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.dropDownMenuOptions').length) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, thank you A. Wolff and does make perfect sense what you've done.  Again my thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will work but you can give it a try

```
// Step 1 : Use below event to identify scrollstop
$(document).bind("scrollstop", function(e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Step2 : Stop the propagation for the mouse up event
});
```

You can create a jsfiddle and give it a try.